# Как на сайте интернет-магазина сделать разные цены в зависимости от браузера пользователя?

Tags: javascript, html, http

В частности хочу сделать более высокие цены для пользователей техники Apple: комьютеров iMac, ноутбуков MacBook и смартфонов iPhone.

И как по возможности скрыть от пользователя такое повышение цены? Например запоминать IP адрес с которого был заход с техники Apple чтобы пользователь не смог узнать настоящую цену зайдя с другого устройства.

Comment: На другом устройстве может быть другой ip. К тому же сейчас многие используют бесплатные прокси. Универсальных способов нет.

Comment: Системы, выстроенные на лжи и обмане, не выдерживают конкуренции с прямым диалогом с покупателем.

Comment: Почему обман? Приложения в аппсторе всегда стоят дороже. Повышение цены для пользователей Apple это стандартная практика.

Comment: @ОлегУрукхаев предлагаю еще заходящим с консольных браузеров накручивать в пару раз! Повышение цены на товары для устройства - нормальная практика, на левые товары - забавная затея.

Comment: Есть такой вариант. Если пользователь заходит **НЕ** с техники Apple, то показывать **"Скидка 30%!"** и соответственно цену меньше. А если с техники Apple, то написать **"Для понтов скидки не нужны!"** или **"Мы мажоры - нет скидкам"** или **"Взял кредит, зачем скидка."** и цену повыше показывать.